# Why FastCGI is so slow?

Tags: c++, io, fastcgi, lighttpd

Recently I've compared two versions of my C++ application that processes huge files (tens of GBs): a regular executable and fastcgi binary spawned under the lighttpd server. It turned out that fastcgi version was nearly 5 times slower. The program basically reads lots of lines from the files on the disc through FILE descriptors, fcgi version does exaclty the same. So where did the slowdown come from?

Thanks for the comments! My program does the following:

Initialization:
- reads several files opened by fopen() line-by-line using fgets (a file contains several millions of lines)
- builds some data structure in the RAM during files processing
- outputs small log messages to a file on the disk after each file is processed

Dialog:
- the rest of time answers search queries via stdin/stdout

And the FCGI version:
FCGX_Init()

Intialization (just as it was in the original version)

while (FCGX_Accept()) {
    Dialog (through fcgi socket instead of stdin/stdout)
}

And I am talking only about initialization part performance. 
I hope there is enough information now.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information. How does it interact with FastCGI? What does it do as a "regular executable?" Clearly something is different other than the move to FastCGI, or there's something going on on stdin/out, but you haven't said what.

Comment: What did the profiler tell you?

Comment: You are giving not enough information to even do a proper guess. There must be some kind of difference in the code your program calls to read those files, you need to identify it.

Comment: I'm starting to think that fastcgi redefines fgets function or something like this. Trying to investigate.

Comment: And? Did you find the problem? I'm experiencing a similar problem. I'm accessing/parsing a PDF file (60kb) from disk. When the program gets called through FastCGI, it's terribly slow and the CPU sky-rockets. The PDF parsing is done by a shared library, so (not) including fastcgi_stdio.h or using NO_FCGI_DEFINES makes no difference.

Comment: Well, technically I solved the performance problem by passing -O2 option to the compiler:) I don't know what it was exactly, though.